# Effect of hydration on CaO in calcium looping

Tags: carbon

How does hydration increase the lifetime of CaO in [calcium looping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_looping)?

Comment: Possible homework question?

Comment: what do you mean?